# Что за асинхронный синтаксис?

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

Всем привет, начал смотреть видео по редакс саге.

И наткнулся на такой код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня очень сильно смутила функция фетч дата, которая не просто возвращала промис от запроса, а делала то, чего я никогда не видел :(

Что на самом деле возвращает fetchData?
Неужели он возвращает промис, который уже выполнил json сериализацию?

Если бы код был на async/await, и имел бы такой вид, вопросов бы не было:

```
const response = await fetch(url);
const data = await response.json();
return data;
```

Я решил попробовать этот код

```
function fetchData() {
  return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'")
  .then(res => res.json());
} 

fetchData().then(console.log)
```

но у меня промис возвращает пустой объект {}

В видео мы передаем в call эту функцию и она нам возвратила сериализованные данные ответа

Как это произошло? Это особенности redux-saga (вроде это просто обычные генераторы)? Заранее спасибо за ответы

Comment: Во-первых, не сериализацию, а ДЕсериализацию. Во-вторых, вы просто опечатались в ссылке — после `/todos/1'` лишняя кавычка стоит

Comment: @andreymal, Действительно. Не заметил, спасибо. Тое сть если возвращать значение из цепочки промисов, возвратится последнее действие из .then? Или как это работает? С асинхронщиной проблем вроде нет.

Comment: В целом всё так. Если вы перепишете функцию fetchData на async/await, то скорее всего всё тоже будет работать (любая async-функция тоже возвращает промис)

Comment: @andreymal, Понял, спасибо. По асинк эвейт вопросов нет. А вот с синтаксисом возвращения последнего промиса из цепочки then встречаюсь впервые

Comment: Почитайте всё таки документацию по промисам